# Can I check if a table exists before join?

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem. I have Table A and would like to join to table B if table B exists. Can this be done? I am only writing SQL in WorkBench to try achieve it.

I am aware I cannot use the EXISTS option as I have tried typing it out but it prompts for an error.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That is very unusual. Why do you need this?

Comment: After transposing my data I actually save the results into a table(B) so I can join with my main table(A). My problem arises when there are no records retrieved due to the where conditions thus the table is not created. Hence my need to check if table (B) exists.

Comment: @juergend : I needed this in a Entity Framework 6 migration script (C#). When applying migrations in this framework, SQL statements from various migration definitions are collected first and executed in a batch as required. Now I had the case where some migration should take data from another schema. If that schema not present it can just skip that step. If that table is not there, the migration infrastructure must not add this SQL to the batch, otherwise it will not compile and break the whole batch.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do this using EXECUTE, so using a query that is only prepared at runtime:

```
SET @sqlCommand = IF(
    EXISTS (SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '{{yourschemaname}}' AND table_name = '{{yourtablename}}' AND column_name = '{{yourcolumnname}}'), 
    'SELECT \'Yes! Good to go!\' as ColumnExists',
    'SELECT \'Nope!\' as ColumnExists');
PREPARE executable FROM @sqlCommand;
EXECUTE executable;
```

Note that the two selects at the center (Yes!/No!) are the custom statements that are to be executed conditionally. So if the column exists, the first command is executed (select 'yes!'), otherwise the second one (select 'nope').

I got the hint from this discussion here.. have a look if you're looking for the MSSQL equivalent: https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/97579/check-if-table-exists-in-join.html

Answer (score 0):

Data manipulation language statements are typically written for a specific schema; you are assumed to know what the schema looks like when you issue the statement. So you don't generally have the capacity to ask whether a particular schema object exists or has a particular structure. You could however write a stored procedure that did different things depending upon the schema. You have the ability in a stored procedure to use conditional statements and to look in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.